# method not extracting numeric value

Tags: java, methods, int

I am trying to extract a numeric value from a CSV file but I am not able to compile my code. I keep getting the following error: Incompatible types: Unexpected return value. I am fairly new to all of this so I'm having a bit of trouble sorting all of this out. Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated . My code is below.

```
   public void numberOfExporters(CSVParser parser, String exportItem) {     
    int exportnum = 0;
    for (CSVRecord record: parser) {
        String exports = record.get("Exports");
        if(exports.contains(exportItem) && (exportnum > 0 )){
            exportnum++;  
        }
      return exportnum;
    }
    System.out.println(exportnum);
}

public void tester3() {
   FileResource fr = new FileResource();
   CSVParser parser = fr.getCSVParser();
   numberOfExporters(parser, "porkbellies");
}
```

Comment: When I Google the error message I get a ton of results describing the problem and solution. Please explain how none of those were any help to you.

Comment: Probably because I am new at this and I googled just like you and tried some of those options and either I was doing it wrong or not understanding the concept. If you want to help, then help. Don't be mean and respond with condescending questions like you just gave.

Comment: You googled and tried, but didn't explain any of that or show us the code for it? Saying "I'm new" is no excuse.

Comment: What I did do is explain to you what I have tried and give you an idea of what direction I was going in. 
Again, If you don't want to mentor or give help, don't respond. Being MEAN is not an excuse.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you describe what you tried - you just dumped code from 1 attempt...

Comment: Look, just stop it. It's obvious you're no help. What am I supposed to do, post everything that I've tried into the post?! Thats absurd. Anyhow, I figured it out on my own....

Comment: Yes, that is what you are supposed to do - it is expected that you comply with [The Help Center Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please read them before posting again.

Comment: Again, I got it sorted out without you or your commentary.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the method as **void**.

That means: it returns nothing. If you want to return an int value, replace void with int.

Beyond that, the whole logic of your method is flawed - you need return statements on all paths that can exit the method, and you are missing a return in case the loop is never entered.

Then: you probably can't iterate that csv parser object as you are trying.

The real answer here: step back, and read books / tutorials. Your code is filled up with basic mistakes. Meaning - forget about doing csv parsing for now. Instead learn how to write simple code for simple problems first.

Comment: I thought about that based on a post I read online about setting this up. I should have it set up like this:

Comment: 'public int numberOfExporters(CSVParser parser, int exportnum, String exportItem)'

Comment: The key point : you don't learn how to ride a bicycle by reading some blog entry... Seriously: you are overburdening yourself. Step back and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your method to be `void` but you have a `return` statement. Either remove the `return` statement or change the method's signature to `int`.

Comment: Ok, I changed the first method but unfortunately and its compiling but its giving me an answer of "No Item Found' when I know that there is an item that should result in a number.

'    int exportnum = 0;
        for (CSVRecord record: parser) {
            String exports = record.get("Exports");
            if(exports.contains(exportItem) && (exportnum > 0 )){
                exportnum++;
                System.out.println(exportnum);
            }
          else {
              System.out.println("NO ITEM FOUND");
            }'

Comment: By the way, thank you for input. You're the only person on this thread that gave solid input as to how to fix the problem.